# Excel VBA failed to load DLL with 53 error code when opened the second time

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I have built a c++ DLL export some functions which would be called in VBA. My Excel version is 2016. And I built the DLL in Visual Studio 2017.

When I create a new excel file with the following vba code, it works. However, when I open that excel file and try to run again, it complains "file not found" with error code 53.

So I have to keep creating new file and pasting code again and again in order to run it.

Any suggestions please? Thanks.

```
Private Declare Function login Lib "XXX.dll" Alias "_login@0" () As Boolean
Private Declare Function logout Lib "XXX.dll" Alias "_logout@0" () As Boolean


Sub test()
    b = login()
    logout
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

If I open the workbook by Open File dialog box in Excel (I have to select the file in its directory in that dialog box), the DLL could be loaded. If I double click the workbook to open it, the DLL failed to load.

Comment: Have you tried including the path in the `Lib` section?

Comment: Yes, I tried include the full absolute path but not work.